# Error on one of my pages

Tags: php, html, mysql, urlencode

I uploaded my first site to the internet.

Everything is working after some tweaking here and there except for one page; this page just loads forever before I get an error message `This webpage is not available ERR_TIMED_OUT`.

I was not getting this problem when I was testing on localhost using `XAMPP`. Are there any common causes for this I should know about?

Its probably worth mentioning that this is the only page on the website which uses `urlencode` to determine which record of something to display from `MySQL`. Other pages also use mysql but no urlencode.

I would put a link to the site so you can see but I'm not ready for the world to see it just yet if it still has problems. (*I hope you understand*)

Any help will be much appreciated!

here is the code for that page

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $somethingID = $_GET['anIDhere'];

    $username = "x";
    $password = "x";
    $hostname = "x";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect to database");
    $selected= mysql_select_db("aDatabaseHere", $db_handle);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM something WHERE id ='$somethingID'") or die ("oops");

    //assigns some details about the records found above to some variables
   //
   //
     }                
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><!-- <!doctype html> -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <title>x</title>
   <link href="../style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="x"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header">
         <div id="headerWrap">
            <div id="headerWrapLogo">
               <a href="../index.php"><img id="logo" src="x"/></a>
            </div>
            <div id="headerWrapRest">
              <div id="headerWrapRestTop" >
              </div>
              <div id="headerWrapRestBottom">
                   <div>
                    <a href="somthing">x</a>
                    <a href="somthing">x</a>
                    <a href="somthing">x</a>
                    <a href="somthing">x</a>
                         <div id="searchdiv">
                         <a form which does something and is not the problem>
                    </div>   
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="middle">
            <div id="codehere">
               <?php
                  echo $somestuff;
                  echo $otherstuff;
               ?>   
         </div>
         some open source javascript here
   </body>
</html>
```

Also I know I shouldn't be using these msql_ methods, i will change that soon, before someone has a go at me.

Comment: Is anything in your PHP or Apache error log?

Comment: try commenting out every line in your php file/page and releasing one per one to see where the error comes from. (If it is truly from `urlencode`)

Comment: Could you please post some lines of your code/page that has erros ?

Comment: nothing in my error log, just checked.

Comment: guys sorry i couldn't add any more detail but i found the problem anyway. I had a "-" as part of the urlencode which it did not like. So i just kept the urlencode as just letters and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Using some quotes from the Life of Brian movie which I watched again last nite:

```
Prophet III: ...through Hebediah, his servants. There shall
in that time be rumours, of things going astray. Ehm...and
there
shall be a great confusion as to where things really are.
And nobody will really know where lieth those little things
wi...with a
sort of rackey work base, that has an attachment. At this
time, a friend shall lose his friend's hammer, and the young
shall not
know where lieth the things possessed by their fathers, that
their fathers put there only just the night before, 'bout
eight
o'clock.
```

so using that, i think you have some things that have attachments to other things, and it has created certain things to go astray

Comment: this did indeed make me chuckle, but I doubt it will solve OPs problem.

Comment: the negative points are worth it then :>

Comment: sorry Drew, the negative points where not from me!

Comment: @Martin glad to cause an occasional smile. u get my vote

Comment: Thanks, although I feel I'm not as worthy as Biggus Dickus.

Comment: *Nutbar!* - [nice plug btw...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913499/display-data-from-a-while-loop#comment53655272_32913499) ehhh God luv ya ;-)

Comment: That does not deserve a negative from my side! `;-)`

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari Good movie though.

Answer (score 1):

Amusing as Drew Pierce is, you need to:

i) Check your DNS - is your website (s)FTP host (the place you put the files) actually available for the browser (*http://*) to reach on the web?

This can take up to 24 hours.

ii) Check you do not have any issues or errors with your .htaccess file, if used, if you have one, remove it and see if the site loads correctly.

iii) try CTRL - F5 to force refresh from the server rather than from any intermediary cache.

***Additionally***

iV)  if other pages on your site work, then simply comment out the PHP code and/or the mySQL code and reupload and see if the page works. If this is so then the error is definitely in the PHP/MySQL.

V) Using the (v), read up on Stack Overflow and insert proper error logging to your page, and then read what the error log reports.

vi) It is **Strongly** suggested you do not use MySQL but instead learn into the improved, MySQL*i*,as the former is deprecated and no longer maintained and is full of security flaws and holes. MySQLi is the way you should be going from this point (PDO as well).

vii) Use a site like http://redbot.org/ to check the header information. See if it returns a code 200 or otherwise what code number it returns?

viii) For clarity - 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM something WHERE id ='$somethingID'") or die ("oops");

should be encased in an `IF` statement so that the MySQL does not fire if the value of `$somethingID` is zero or non-numeric. :

```
if ($somethingID > 0 && is_numeric($somethingId)){ 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM something WHERE id ='$somethingID'") or die ("oops");
}
```

This is really just for tidiness but otherwise the SQL is searching using an empty value which might cause issues.

Comment: as much as i tried to help, i would go for this answer

Comment: guys sorry i couldn't add any more detail but i found the problem anyway. I had a "-" as part of the urlencode which it did not like. So i just kept the urlencode as just letters and it works. Thank you very much for you're help though.